# Regex for lines from /etc/passwd and /etc/group

Tags: java, regex, passwd

I've been working on a small Java problem set and have come across some trouble. I'm not very experienced writing regular expressions and could really use two for verifying line entries in /etc/group and /etc/passwd in Java.

I found [Regex Verification of Line in /etc/passwd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118880/regex-verification-of-line-in-etc-passwd) earlier and have yet to test it, but it looks adaptable for what I need. Could anyone else help in providing a regex string for either file?

I'm looking to verify user-entered passwd and group lines, in java, before writing them out to disk. If not, I'll likely end up tokenizing each piece and running various expensive operations.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than writing a regex you should probably just read the files with [`Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and parse each line with [`String.split(":")`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). Then you can check that each part is valid without dealing with a complex expression to handle all cases. It'll probably be easier to write the code and easier to read it later.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use regular expressions? Just split the line on the colons and inspect the pieces.